# i want to use addEvent instead of onkeyup in html

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, addeventlistener, onkeyup

```
<td valign="top"><center>
<textarea id="ta_in" rows="7" cols="42" onkeyup="get_ml()"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="ta_out" rows=7" cols="42"></textarea></center>
</td>
```

//javascript file.

```
function get_ml()
{
en  = "|" + document.getElementById("ta_in").value;
ml = "";
n = 0;
.....
.....
.....
document.getElementById("ta_out").value = ml;
}
```

//i need to use addEvent instead of onkeyup

Comment: Just do it, man. We don't mind. :p But those implicit globals gotta go. The rhino is *not* happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For modern browser compatibility, you would use `addEventListener` like this:

```
document.getElementById("ta_in").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    var en  = "|" + document.getElementById("ta_in").value;
    var ml = "";
    var n = 0;
    .....
    .....
    .....
    document.getElementById("ta_out").value = ml;
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6QMFV/

You would just run this code after your page has been loaded, by either placing the code at the end of your page (just before `</body>`) or by putting it in a function that you call from just before `</body>` or by calling this code for an event handler that listens for an event that tells you the page is loaded.

Comment: @suneeshtr - What isn't working? You didn't include a full piece of code and you don't say what isn't working so there's not much more we can do but show you the proper structure.  If you implement it properly, this structure will work just fine.  If you make mistakes in the implementation (which you haven't shown us), then your mistakes might keep it from working.  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6QMFV/